# Get Where method from Queryable

Tags: c#

Following query returning two Where methods from a `Queryable`:

```cs
    var foundedMethods = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(Queryable.Where) && 
                    m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .Where(p => p.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>)
                    && p.GetParameters().Last().ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Expression<>)).ToList();
```

I got two `Where` method calls against the `Queryable`. But, I need only the following:

```
Where<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,Boolean>>)
```

What adding filters I need to add in above query? Any guides and help how I filter methods by specific parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the style of the question, checking that the func also has the correct number of generic args will suffice as the other overload returned has one extra (`Func<TSource,Int32,Boolean>`)

It'd be a good idea to do the same type checking as the expression arguments on the Func, but it's *currently* unnecessary.

```
var foundedMethods = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(Queryable.Where)
                && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .Where(p => p.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>)
                && p.GetParameters().Last().ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Expression<>)
                // Ensure Func has 2 args
                && p.GetParameters().Last().ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().First().GetGenericArguments().Length == 2)
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, a hack-y way to do it is find the method signature directly by matching on `MethodInfo.ToString()`

```cs
var foundedMethods = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.ToString() ==
        "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TSource] Where[TSource](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TSource], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[TSource,System.Boolean]])")
    .ToList();
```